# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' on python

Tags: python

I have been getting this error whenever I use pygame, idk why, plz help

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
screen_width = 1280
screen_height = 960
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('pong')
    
while True:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
    
pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(60)
```

when i run this, i get like 2 paragraphs aout, Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CAMetalLayer setDisplaySyncEnabled:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe5cb452ed0' *** First throw call stack:

how do i fix it?

Comment: you should include the full stack trace

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue running Pygame on OSx with Anaconda. I narrowed it down to this line:

```
pygame.display.set_mode()
```

Other lines in pygame run just fine. I ended up solving it by uninstalling pygame and reinstalling a different version. Try this in terminal:

```
pip uninstall pygame
sudo pip3 install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

Comment: I just had the same issue and this answer solved it for me. Thanks!